# Onclick change border-bottom to a div by classname and set dark mode on/off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dark mode JavaScript and it changes the background color and text font color perfect but I need it to also change the border-bottom of the div class name `.veritas` and that part is not working

Here is the code:

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggleBtn");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var borderBottom = document.getElementById(".veritas");


toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var bgColor, textColor;

  if (body.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is on";
    bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
    textColor = "#101010";
    borderBottom = "#101010";

  } else {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is off";
    bgColor = "#101010";
    textColor = "#FFFFFF";
    borderBottom = "#FFFFFF";
  }

  body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  body.style.color = textColor;
  borderBottom.style.borderBottom = borderBottom;


  // Save the chosen colors to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("bgColor", bgColor);
  localStorage.setItem("textColor", textColor);
  localStorage.setItem("borderBottom", borderBottom);
});

// Retrieve saved colors from localStorage
var savedBgColor = localStorage.getItem("bgColor");
var savedTextColor = localStorage.getItem("textColor");
var savedBordersColor = localStorage.getItem("borderBottom");

if (savedBgColor && savedTextColor) {
  body.style.backgroundColor = savedBgColor;
  body.style.color = savedTextColor;
  borderBottom.style.borderBottom = borderBottom;
  if (savedBgColor === "#101010" && savedTextColor === "#FFFFFF") {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is off";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #101010;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.veritas {
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #101010;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleBtn">Dark mode is on</button>
<div class="veritas">
  border-bottom should change color in dark/light mode
</div>
```

Any idea why this does not change the `border-bottom` in the div class name `.veritas`?

I created a Codepen to see it in action
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/gOQMrjX

Comment: Although you can simplify this and there is a lot that I want to change, I believe your issue is that veritas has a class but you are referencing with **document.getElementById(".veritas");** You can replace **getElementById** with **querySelector**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this

```js
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggleBtn");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var borderDiv=document.getElementsByClassName("veritas")[0];

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var bgColor, textColor,borderBottom;

  if (body.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is on";
    bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
    textColor = "#101010";
      borderBottom = "#101010";
      
  } else {
    body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    toggleBtn.textContent = "Dark mode is off";
    bgColor = "#101010";
    textColor = "#FFFFFF";
      borderBottom = "#FFFFFF";
  }
  body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  body.style.color = textColor;
  borderDiv.style.borderBottomColor = borderBottom;

});
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
height:100%;
}
.dark-mode {
background-color: #101010;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.veritas{width:90%;
border-bottom:1px solid #101010;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleBtn">Dark mode is on</button>
<div class="veritas">
border-bottom should change color in dark/light mode
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for the first div with classname .veritas, but I have in reality around 5 divs with the same class and only the first one changed color but not the rest of them but it is starting to work

Comment: if you want to apply these changes on multiple divs best way is to assign a class to all the divs and then change the class name or border color property by looping through these divs.

Comment: I did, look at this codepen updated with your code , https://codepen.io/familias/pen/gOQMrjX all divs have the same classname but only the first one changes color

Comment: Here is the solution https://codepen.io/iffi45/pen/LYXZdpW

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors

1 `.veritas` is a class and you are access it using

```
borderBottom=document.getElementById(".veritas");.
```

Change it to using className

```
var borderBottom=document.getElementsByClassName("veritas")[0];
```

or querySelector

```
var borderBottom=document.querySelector(".veritas");
```

2 . `borderBottom.style.borderBottom = borderBottom;` this should contain `width style color`, while you are only supplying color,
change all the occurrences of

```
borderBottom = "#FFFFFF";
```

to

```
borderBottom = "1px solid #FFFFFF";
```

Comment: One could also use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`...  One could also use the cascade of CSS to just add a rule `.dark-mode .veritas { border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; }` instead of using JavaScript unnecessarily.

Comment: I tried the cascade of CSS as written by Heretic and it worked. The code change in the answer did not worked. Could you please add it as answer Heretic Monkey ?